# Rectangle under a parabola.

Tags: integration

You are given that $y=-x^2$ find a show the maxium area you can create using a rectangle with its bottom edge along the $x$ axis and its top two corners lie on the curve $y=-x^2$.

Any idea?

Comment: There is no such a rectangle. You can find rectangles arbitrarily large. So, are you sure your question is correct? Also, please edit the tags. It is not related to integration nor graph-theory.

Comment: I think you confused *bottom* and the *top* here, because $y = -x^2$ never goes beyond (higher?) $x$ axis.

Comment: I don't understand.  I'm having trouble thinking about where the rectangle could possibly  be.

Comment: Draw a picture. There is probably a typo, I would guess the parabola is $A-x^2$ for some positive constant $A$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas that would make a lot of sense.

Comment: If the bottom edge is the x-axis the *bottom* edge has y = 0.  so the corners have y > 0.  but y = -$x^2$ is never greater than zero.

Comment: I thought it could be an error but it was typed twice.

Comment: The question is clearly ill defined or the "teacher" attempted demonstrating a point...

Answer (score 3):

I am going to presume that the question was $y = C - x^2$, since that would make more sense.

This is an optimization problem, because it has the word "maximum" in it.  But first, you have to setup an equation to generate the area before you find the maximum of the area.

So, first, what is the equation of the area of a rectangle? $a = length\cdot width$.

So, on this rectangle, what will be the width?  Since the parabola is centered around the $x$ axis, it will be 2 times the $x$ value, or $2x$.  What will be the height?  It will be the value of the $y$ for the given $x$.  So $a = 2x\cdot y$.

Now, we have an equation for the $y$ value, $y = C - x^2$.  Therefore we can substitute: $a = 2x\cdot (C - x^2)$.  This simplifies to $a = 2Cx - 2x^3$.

Now, if you take the derivative, you can use the derivative to find the maximum value of this function.